# PowerMockito: doThrow unfinished stubbing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

I am trying to simulate a failure condition in my JUnit test by throwing an exception. However, it seems I am failing to stub some method correctly.

My code is as follows:

```
private MyClass mockObject;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockObject = PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockObject);
}

@Test
public void testFailure() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.doThrow(new Exception("This is a test exception.")).when(mockObject).register(anyString());
    ...
}
```

, where the return type of `register` is `void`.

However, when I execute this test, I get an unfinished stubbing exception on the `doThrow` call.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:36)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

Can anyone help identify what I am missing here?

In case it helps, the dependency versions are 1.5.6 for both powermock-api-mockito and powermock-module-junit4 in my pom.

Comment: That looks right, did you `@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)`? Is your register method final? Or MyClass final?

Comment: Yes, I did annotate the class with `PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)`, where the new instance of MyClass is getting created in the constructor. As for being final, both method as well as class are not final.

Comment: If your class is being created in the constructor, where is your CLassUnderTest being created relative to the whenNew call in your test case?

Comment: It's actually after the doThrow call in my test method, but I omitted that in the example. It's like this:
`ClassUnderTest helper = new ClassUnderTest();`. The test method contains only these two lines.

Comment: The issue turned out to be with a static mock unrelated to this code. I had `mockStatic(AnotherClass.class); doNothing().when(AnotherClass.class);` in the @BeforeClass method. after removing the doNothing() line, the test works fine.
Thanks for the help..

Comment: Can you please answer your question and accept the response? To highlight that you don't need help anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with a static mock unrelated to this code. I had mockStatic(AnotherClass.class); doNothing().when(AnotherClass.class); in the @BeforeClass method. after removing the doNothing() line, the test works fine. Thanks everyone for the help.